# Cannot create a new python notebook on google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I tried to create a new python3 notebook on google colab, it returns the error message:

Colab fail to load
Error loading https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
Error: Error loading https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
    at HTMLScriptElement.k.onerror (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/gapi_loader.js:9:415)

I tried to reinstall chrome and close all ad-block extensions, but none of these seem to work. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/525#issuecomment-487107300) --

> A common cause of this error is Chrome extensions which block access
>   to the https://apis.google.com/js/client.js library.
>
> I'd recommend trying to load the page in an incognito window with all
>   extensions disabled. If the problem vanishes, it's likely that you'll
>   need to whitelist the colab.research.google.com hostname in one of
>   your extensions which blocks resource fetches.